# Automated browser based testing on ChromeOS

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-os

Is there a way to automate testing on ChromeOS? like selenium based test scripts for chrome browser running on a Chrome OS device ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some google chrome extensions that provide similar capabilities. The first one that popped up in a Google search was this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghost-inspector-web-test/aicdiabnghjnejfempeinmnphllefehc?hl=en-US